# How to add raven platform in Cooja simulator?

Tags: operating-system, contiki

I am using Cooja simulator for contiki based WSN. I have to use raven platform, but i couldn't find "raven" in Add new mote-mote type wizard.How to add raven or avr platform in Cooja?

Answer (score 0):

The Raven support was implemented by David Kopf. It is not yet merged with the official Cooja. You can find it at https://github.com/fros4943/cooja-avrora-patch-wip/tree/davidkopf 
Unfortunately it seems like the work has stalled.